# How can I test stunnel?

Tags: ubuntu, stunnel

I've created a conf file for a connection to an address and port for stunnel whose location is in /usr/local/etc/stunnel/ and started the stunnel service.

I've binded the address to my local ip address 127.0.0.1:60005

To test the connection, I've tried to connect the address via telnet with:

> telnet 127.0.0.1 60005

Turns:

> Trying 127.0.0.1... Connected to 127.0.0.1. Escape character is '^]'. 
>   Connection closed by foreign host.

I know that connection is not closed by foreign host as I tried telnet with the original ip address, there is no problem.

So,
how can I test my stunnel connection except using telnet?
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to test it is to use `tcpdump`.

Try: `tcpdump port 60005 -n -vvvv`

Then send some data to that interface: `echo "blah" > nc localhost 60005`

You should see packets from `tcpdump`; if you do not see any packets try having `tcpdump` listen on a different interface with the `-i` switch.

Answer (score 0):

```
tcpdump port 60005 -n -vvvv,
echo "blah" > nc localhost 60005**
```

showed me just what I needed to see. Only thing I had to do was change the port number.